# Is hardcoded object properties in the angular template perform better in browser when compared to having a pipe to read value

Tags: angular, performance, typescript, angular2-template, maintainability

I am working on an Angular project which contains 24 modules and due to customer requirements, there are always changes to the code.

We have 2 approaches in hand

1. Using the object with keys directly in the template itself. 
   Sample code looks like : {{ object?.property1?.property2 }}
2. I have written a pipe which takes the object and the path to get the value from. I have stored the path value in the constant. In the future, we want to drive these constants from the database.
   Sample code looks like: {{ object | deepFind: PROPERTY1_PROPERTY2_PATH }}

Here PROPERTY1_PROPERTY2_PATH is a constant and it contains the value of 'property1.property2';

I have written a sample in stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsqhk4

I tried to validate the performance difference between these 2 approaches But I didn't find any difference in rendering times.

I tried to use Chrome Dev Tools Performance Tab and the deepfind method just took 7ms.

I was unable to figure out to which approach we need to vote for?

```
<ul>
    <!-- Approach 1 -->
    <li *ngFor="let widget of serverResponse.widgets">
        {{ widget?.title }}
    </li>
    <!-- Approach 2 -->
    <li *ngFor="let widget of serverResponse | deepFind: WIDGET_CONSTANTS?.WIDGETS_LIST">
        {{ widget | deepFind: WIDGET_CONSTANTS?.WIDGET_HEADING }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have multiple questions on this problem

1. I didn't find any way to calculate the performance of the angular 2 template rendering. So, I tried the naive approach to check the bottom up and see what is the performance of the pipe. Please suggest me a way to check the performance to calculate angular 2 template rendering.
2. I know that this should be an impure pipe. What is the performance decrease using more pipes in the template rather than hardcoded object properties?. Because here just I showed only 2 pipes but in my project is more than 100 times.
3. What will a better approach to handle this case for future maintenance, code readability and standard way to handle this problem?
4. I know that I am passing objects to the pipe what is affect the on performance when compared to passing a primitive value?
5. We are nowhere hardcoding the object keys in the ts file also. I need a better solution to have a solution to handle in the template as well as ts file.
6. What are the other approaches to the above problem?​